# How to auto-upload local project file changes on remote server via Eclipse RSE?

Tags: eclipse, ftp, synchronization, sftp, eclipse-rse

I have a local PHP project in my Eclipse workspace and a remote server that I want my project files to be synchronized on everytime I change my files. So far I've installed Remote System Explorer (RSE) into Eclipse, set up a SFTP connection to the remote server and checked out the project on the desired remote path via SVN. I already found out that via RSE I can export my project onto the server (which is not necessary any more) or configure the remote path as new project (which I tried but throws a CoreException everytime I try to open a file).

Now, is there a way to just set up an auto-upload/sync for every file change on my local project to the remote path, just like you can do easily on PHPStorm? Or am I stuck with manually uploading my local changes...?

Comment: have you perhaps found a solution?

Comment: nope, I couldn't find any, I suppose Eclipse just isn't capable. I've resorted to a different IDE for now.

Comment: can you share what IDE?

Comment: NetBeans. It's free as well and also supports remote syncing.

Comment: Same problem, it's IMHO primary IDE behavior in these days, strange that Eclipse doesnt have it... just shame, that NetBeans cannot use Tabnine :(